# How to use AppCompatPreferenceActivity with nested Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I try to add my custom actionbar on the Preference Fragment.

I try it like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281205/493t), but it doesn't work with nested Preferences.

Is there any clean way to implement this?