# Adding toolbar to PreferenceActivity via AppCompatPreferenceActivity causes overlapping

Tags: android

I had gone through [How to add toolbars to AppCompatPreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114730/how-to-use-appcompatpreferenceactivity)

I'm using `appcompat-v7:23.0.1` and `support-v4:23.0.1`

Before using `AppCompayPreferenceActivity`, my `PreferenceActivity` looks the following without toolbar.

[image]

### Without Toolbar

```
public class JStockPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Display the fragment as the main content.
            JStockPreferenceFragment jStockPreferenceFragment = JStockPreferenceFragment.newInstance();
            jStockPreferenceFragment.setArguments(this.getIntent().getExtras());
            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, jStockPreferenceFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

After using `AppCompayPreferenceActivity`, with some `Toolbar` initialization code, the outcome looks as the following

[image]

The outcome isn't as expected :-

1. The `Toolbar` overlaps with `PreferenceFragment`
2. When touching on `Toolbar`, the event will be consumed by `PreferenceFragment`. This means, when you touch on toolbar, "Table header" preference will be touched instead.

### With Toolbar

```
public class JStockPreferenceActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Display the fragment as the main content.
            JStockPreferenceFragment jStockPreferenceFragment = JStockPreferenceFragment.newInstance();
            jStockPreferenceFragment.setArguments(this.getIntent().getExtras());
            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, jStockPreferenceFragment).commit();
        }
        initToolbar();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
            toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar, root, false);
            root.addView(toolbar, 0);
        } else {
            toolbar = null;
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My toolbar is

### toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <!-- android:elevation="4dp" is used due to http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android- -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I was wondering, what I had did wrong, which causes `Toolbar` overlapped with `PreferenceFragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and getting advice from [Ian Lake](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116311379832695909648/posts/SRZrjGD1uhj), I manage to make it work by

1. Change from `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`, to `AppCompatActivity`+`PreferenceFragmentCompat`

The following solution is workable for API 10 and above.

---

### JStockPreferenceActivity.java

```
public class JStockPreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.jstock_preference_activity);

        initToolbar();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Display the fragment as the main content.
            JStockPreferenceFragment jStockPreferenceFragment = JStockPreferenceFragment.newInstance();
            jStockPreferenceFragment.setArguments(this.getIntent().getExtras());
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, jStockPreferenceFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

### JStockPreferenceFragment.java

```
public class JStockPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceDisplayDialogCallback {

    public static JStockPreferenceFragment newInstance() {
        return new JStockPreferenceFragment();
    }
```

---

However, by doing so, there is a shortcoming. Your previous custom `DialogPreference` no longer work. To solve this, you need to

1. Replace `DialogPreference` with `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`.
2. Replace `DialogPreference` in XML with `ListPreference`. (I'm not exactly sure whether `ListPreference` as replacement is a right way. It works anyway)
3. Manually show `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`, in `PreferenceFragmentCompat`'s `onPreferenceDisplayDialog`.

---

### JStockPreferenceFragment.java

```
public class JStockPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceDisplayDialogCallback {

    public static JStockPreferenceFragment newInstance() {
        return new JStockPreferenceFragment();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Showing custom dialog preference.
    private void showPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat preferenceDialogFragmentCompat) {
        preferenceDialogFragmentCompat.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        preferenceDialogFragmentCompat.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragment.DIALOG");
    }

    private void showCurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat(Preference preference) {
        CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat currencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat = CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.newInstance(preference.getKey());
        showPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat(currencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat);
    }

    // Showing custom dialog preference.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Callback when we are using custom dialog preference.
    @Override
    public Fragment getCallbackFragment() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceDisplayDialog(PreferenceFragmentCompat preferenceFragmentCompat, Preference preference) {
        final String key = preference.getKey();

        if (_CURRENCY_SYMBOL_OPTIONS.equals(key)) {
            showCurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat(preference);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    // Callback when we are using custom dialog preference.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

### CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java

```
public class CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat extends PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat {

    public CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat() {
    }

    public static CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat newInstance(String key) {
        CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat fragment = new CurrencySymbolPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat();
        Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putString("key", key);
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            ...
            this.getPreference().setSummary(getSummary());
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

### preferences.xml

```
<android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference
    android:title="@string/preference_currency_symbol_title"
    android:key="_CURRENCY_SYMBOL_OPTIONS" />
```

Please note that, you need to add the following item in your theme.

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

### Some bugs regarding theme

However, the theme-ing isn't perfect yet - [PreferenceFragmentCompat requires preferenceTheme to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)

This is a known issues : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183376

There is proposed workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108439/72437 But, the workaround will only work for v14 and above, not v7 and above.